# Set width in percentage to absolutely positioned elements

Tags: html, css

I have created my own dropdown list, but I have a problem with its width. I have `#leftDiv` which takes 30% of the page, then comes my dropdown list which should take 100% width of the `#leftDiv`. It does, but my list, which appears on click, is absolutely positioned and takes 100% of the window itself. Even if I set the width to 30%, it takes 30% of the whole page. How can I make my list to be the same size? Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vaxobasilidze/rfwearbw/

Press `--- TYPE ---` to see the problem. Here is my styling for my dropdown list only:

```
#typeSelect {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    background-image:url(images/comment-bg.png);
    background-repeat:repeat;
    background-position:300px;
    width:353px;
    padding:5px;
    line-height:1;
    border-radius:4px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    /*box-shadow:inset 0 0 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.6);*/
    outline:none;
    color: #b8c0c8;
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#typeSelect li {
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
}

#typeDropDownList {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height:1;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    outline:none;
    color: #b8c0c8;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 30%;
}

#typeDropDownList li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    background-image:url(images/cusel-bg-1.png);
    background-repeat:repeat;
    background-position:300px;
    padding:5px;
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#typeDropDownList li:first-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
}

#typeDropDownList li:last-child {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
}

#adapterSettings {
    background: url(images/comment-bg2.png);
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Make sure the container for your list (adapterInput) is set to `position: relative`, otherwise, the list will use the next positioned element up the chain (or the body if there are none) for the width.

Comment: You've made typeselect li relative when it should be relative to adapterInput .

Comment: @delinear Fixed, thank you for your help. I have changed typeDropDownList's positioning to relative and width 100%, also set relative positioning to adapterInput.

Comment: @Highdef Fixed, thank you!

Comment: @VaxoBasilidze No problem :)

Comment: @Highdef Oh, just noticed, that changing positioning from absolute to relative caused a problem, dropdown list moves other elements when appears. How can I fix this?

Comment: Which class did you change from absolute to relative and which elements is it moving?

Comment: @Highdef I changed #typeDropDownList's position, and it moves everything below it down when the list appears

Answer (score 0):

First, give the dropdown 100% width:

```
#typeDropDownList {
  width: 100%
}
```

and you want the width to be 100% relative to `settingsDiv`:

```
#settingsDiv {
  position: relative;
}
```

And oops, now part of the drop-down is hidden. That is because it is now relative to `settingsDiv` and `settingsDiv`'s height does not take consideration of expanded dropdown.

When dropdown is set to `absolute`, there is no way for the `settingsDiv` to automatically change the height to fit the dropdown without JS, you can probably hard-code `settingDivs`'s height:

```
#settingsDiv {
  position: relative;
  height: 230px;    }
```

---

**But you want settingsDiv height to automatically accommodate dropdown's height?**

Then remove `position: absolute` from `#typeDropDownList`.

**But dropdown has to be absolute?**

Then remove `overflow: auto;` from `#settingsDiv` - so when dropdown expands, it overflows `settingsDiv`, instead of being contained inside.

Comment: I have tried what you said, but does not work. Here is updated fiddle. Made it more clear what I want. When you press (---TYPE---) dropdown list, it moves other elements down. I want it to appear on top of them without moving them down, like the normal select does. If #typeDropDownList position is absolute, it appears on top, but the width is wrong, if its relative, it moves down other elements. https://jsfiddle.net/vaxobasilidze/rfwearbw/4/

Answer (score 0):

You need take following steps.

Add `position: relative;` for `#leftDiv`.

```
#leftDiv {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
width: 30%;
height: 100%;
border-right: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
box-sizing: border-box;
float: left;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: auto;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.33);
}
```

Remove `width:` property from `#typeDropDownList`:

```
#typeDropDownList {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
line-height: 1;
-webkit-appearance: none;
outline: none;
color: #b8c0c8;
width: 100%;
border-radius: 3px;
box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
display: none;
position: absolute;
z-index: 100;
/* width: 100%; */
}
```

Comment: This makes the list 100% wide to #leftDiv, but it's still not the same size as #typeSelect. Check my fiddle and make these changes to see

Comment: Still same. In your fiddle when dropdown list appears, it moves below inputs down. I want to fix this problem.